Getting dependencies error in paypal and inappview
I have been getting this error i can not reduce the flutter_inappwebview version because of latest xcode updadte,
can you please sugest me any way to use both these pakages together please,

Because flutter_paypal_checkout 1.0.1 depends on flutter_inappwebview ^5.7.2+3 and no versions of flutter_paypal_checkout match >1.0.1 <2.0.0, flutter_paypal_checkout ^1.0.1 requires flutter_inappwebview ^5.7.2+3.
So, because foodly depends on both flutter_paypal_checkout ^1.0.1 and flutter_inappwebview ^6.1.5, version solving failed.
You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:


Consider downgrading your constraint on flutter_inappwebview: flutter pub add flutter_inappwebview:^5.8.0

I can not reduce the inappview version because it is the override error,
please suggest me any other way
